# Rising Edge Latching Flip-Flop

Tags: digital-logic, homework

I'm currently trying to build a rising edge detecting circuit which holds its output until it detects another rising edge using d flip-flops for a homework. Basically the output will change if and only if it detects a rising edge. Holding the input won't change the output. Here is the current logic diagram i got

[image]

Where the states are represented by the current input and current output. From this diagram, here is a table that i got with the K map (In is next state input and On is next state output)

[image]

[image]

But when building it in proteus, i got a falling edge detector instead

Adding a NOT gate for the input fixes this problem

[image]

But this changes the logic functions and resulted in a new one which is pretty illogical

[image]

I think i read my circuit wrong, but i don't know where and how i should've conveyed this circuit into a logic table and state diagram, which is the part i need help with.

Comment: Can I clarify that if a rising edge is sensed, the output should change state? If that is the case there is a very simple solution.

Comment: yes, when a rising edge is sensed, the output should change state. Think of it like one of those lamps that had a latching push buttons where you have to push to turn it on and off and not a switches, so pressing it equals to 1 and not pressing it equals to 0